# Geoserver SLD line ends labeling

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am having a hard time putting labels on both ends of a line 
Here is SLD that I have so far. It puts a label on one side only but I need it on both ends of a line.

---

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>line_name_ends_red</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>line_name_ends_red</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>line_name_ends_red</Name>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>

                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Geometry>
                            <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Geometry>
                      <LabelPlacement>
                       <PointPlacement>
                         <Rotation>
                          <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Function>
                         </Rotation>
                       </PointPlacement>
                      </LabelPlacement>

                      <Label>

                         <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>

                       </Label>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>`

---

[image: this is what my SLD produces]
But I need it to look like this 
[image: But I need it to look like this]

Answer (score 2):

To get two labels you will need two textSymbolizers one for the start point and one for the end point.  So it becomes:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
    <Geometry>
        <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
            <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>
    </Geometry>
    <LabelPlacement>
        <PointPlacement>
            <Rotation>
                <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:Function>
            </Rotation>
        </PointPlacement>
    </LabelPlacement>

    <Label>

        <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>

    </Label>
</TextSymbolizer>
<TextSymbolizer>
  <Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
      <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:Function>
  </Geometry>
  <LabelPlacement>
    <PointPlacement>
      <Rotation>
        <ogc:Function name="startAngle">
          <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>
      </Rotation>
    </PointPlacement>
  </LabelPlacement>

  <Label>

    <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>

  </Label>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: and I suspect if you take out the rotation your labels will end up the right way

Comment: Hi and thank for the response. Yes that did place labels on both ends. But I need them to be always placed away of the line (before and after the line) not along the line. I'd upload how it look like now but I done see how.

Comment: Pointplacement takes an offset parameter which might help