# Display arrows on each segment of a multines feature, using GeoServer and SLD

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, line, sld

I'm using the SLD code below to display arrows along lines with GeoServer 2.10:

```
<Rule>
  <Name>Lines</Name>
  <Title>Lines</Title>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </LineSymbolizer>
  <PointSymbolizer>
    <Geometry>
      <ogc:Function name="centroid">
        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Geometry>
    <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </Mark>
      <Size>20</Size>
      <Rotation>
        <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
          <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>
      </Rotation>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>        
</Rule>
```

This is doing the job properly when features are single lines (straight segments). In the case a feature is a multiline including segments going in various directions, the arrow is displaying wrongly, taking into account the segments all together (on the image below, the arrow is cercled in blue).

[image]

The solution would be to explode the multilines in the database table on which the GeoServer layer relies, but I need to keep my features as multilines. Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: You need to use the start point and end point functions instead of the centroid function

Comment: Thanks! The `centroid` function enables to position the arrow in on the centroid of the polyline. The `startPoint` function will do so on the start point of the feature but will not resolve the problem (to me). Any example of SLD syntax relying on the functions you suggest?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this one?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153117/geoserver-sld-line-ends-labeling